# How to Fix Joomla Administrator Blank Page Issue?

Tags: php, .htaccess, joomla

I am new for Joomla. Frontpage of the website is working fine. When I open the administrator page. It's going to blank. When I open the source code of the administrator page, HTML code is available. I have also set the:

```
public $error_reporting = 'maximum';
```

But didn't get the error also rename the `.htaccess.txt` to `.htaccess.`

I have checked the version.php and found this:

```
const RELEASE = '3.6';
const DEV_LEVEL = '2';
```

Please help.

Comment: Check your server logs for the error that's occurring.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your reply,I didn't check the server log

Comment: Thanks for your reply,
I didn't check the server log.But When I  did the _Inspect Element_ and got the
html {
    display: none;
}
When I unchecked the display:none.Login page is displaying and I logged in.
But still didn't get the solution.

Comment: @MohammadTafsir please check on this link
https://www.ostraining.com/blog/joomla/white-screen-of-death/

Comment: Can you share the link to your website backend ?

Comment: This might be helpful too -
http://serverfault.com/questions/460151/joomla-includes-css-that-makes-display-empty-page